# Saving a users' photo in db via node js API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, photo

I have a node js API using mongoldb and an express web app. 
I need to store my user's profile pictures.

What's the good practices? I've seen that one usually save images on the file system, but I would like to store my images on my API in case I need to access them outside of the web app. How do I send the image from the browser to my API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, and a detailed answer requires knowing more about your stack, but I'll try to include the general components you'll want to get this to work:

- You'll need some middleware that parses multipart file uploads, something like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) may be of interest! Another option is to encode them as base64 in an API request, but this will partially depend on how it's implemented in your client side and how large the files are.
- If you don't want to store the files on the filesystem, you'll want to configure multer to hold them in memory and then store in them mongodb as BSON data (binary data).
- You can use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) for this, MongoDB's method of storing files in MongoDB, but if the files are less than 16MB (which they should be for profile pictures), you don't necessarily need to.
- If you aren't using any client side JS libraries, you can simply create a form with a standard file upload element and submit the form. This will submit it as a multipart file upload. See the [example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file). If you are using a client side JS library, many have plugins for file uploading that can make it a bit easier, but you don't need to use them.

[This blog post](https://ciphertrick.com/2017/02/28/file-upload-with-nodejs-and-gridfs-mongodb/) has a complete example of uploading using node, MongoDB, multer, and GridFS. It doesn't include the browser side code, but you can use either the following example from MDN (referenced earlier) as a basis:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
   <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple>
 </div>
 <div>
   <button>Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Or something more specific to your client side library, such as [this example](https://ciphertrick.com/2016/10/24/file-upload-with-angular2-nodejs/) that uses ng2-file-upload for Angular 2.

Good luck! I hope that helps get you started with some general direction.